# Use special fonts on a wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, fonts, font-face

I would like to use a font I've paid from webtype.com on my wordpress blog. I don't own the blog so I can't change anything in the main php files as function.php. So, the only solution I've found is to add this content in the css customization file :

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "Scout Normal";
     src: url("http://the/url/of/the/file") format("woff");
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
}
.block p {
     font-family: "Scout Normal";
}
```

The problem is that everytime i save the file, Wordpress remove the url in the loading of the font, that means

```
src: url("http://the/url/of/the/file") format("woff");
```

become

```
src: format("woff");
```

Do you have any ideas to force the loading of the font, or an other idea to load it ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: can't you just serve the css as is and not use php?

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't use php, i don't understand ?

Comment: we need more context. how are you including that?

Comment: from the customization page of wordpress. It's a feature you can buy which allows you to add some css rules. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/A0o1jFA.png) which may help you. So you can see how i've added the css.

Comment: then this belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to functions by change it from wordpress backend here: Appearance > Editor

http://prntscr.com/4ddfn4

Comment: No I can't, i don't access to this, I think it is because I don't host the blog.

Comment: Try make Your own style.css put on your host than make @import url('/css/styles.css'); at css in wordpress that You dont have acces to php files.

Comment: No, it's not working, it's impossible if we don't own the wordpress blog.